# How do i store multiple values into one attribute in CoreData?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, core-data

i'm designing a health and fitness application, and i'm in the middle of designing an exercise database. I converted all my exercises from JSON format and stored them into multiple arrays relevant to the muscle group they're associated with. I've created multiple entities for each muscle group and then an attribute named "exercises" inside each entity. The plan is to store the exercises that are relevant to the muscle group into the correct entity. I've tried using a for loop to iterate over the arrays and save the values. However it only seems to save one value from each array into an attribute.

Here's an example of the arrays i would be using to try and save to CoreData...

```
let chestExercises = ["Bench Press", "Incline Press"]
let backExercises = ["Lat Pulldown", "Pullover"]
```

The reason i'm using CoreData to do this is because i want my users to be able to edit/delete any exercises from the database.

I would really appreciate any help, and advice on this approach i'm taking. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a one to many relationship there, so you should make another entity called Exercise and give MuscleGroup a 1:M relationship to it, presuming you don't have any exercises in multiple groups.

You could actually just get away with having muscleGroup being an attribute of Exercise. When you go to select a set of exercises, just give a predicate that filters to the muscle group requested. MuscleGroup could then be a enum and you store an integer denoting which member of the enum each exercise is.

But the proper answer is going to depend on all the data you want to store persistently, like if there are other attributes associated with either MuscleGroup or Exercise.

Comment: Well i would like to store a description (string) unique for each exercise and a picture (string) for each exercise sometime in the future. Thanks for your response.

Comment: So yeah, you don't really need a muscle group entity? It can just be an attribute that lets you filter the exercises with you perform a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I save the array to CoreData.

```
var exerciseName: String = ""
let chestExercises = ["Bench Press", "Incline Press"] as NSArray
let chestString = chestExercises.componentsJoined(by: ",")
exerciseName = chestString
```

Then I have exerciseName set as a String in CoreData.